# Read input from .txt in C++

Tags: c++, input, stdin

I've got a .cpp which is prompted as follows:

```
$ ./program file < file.txt
```

Then I want to use the text on the file.txt for some functions inside my program.
How can I access the input on the .txt on my .cpp?

stdin? 
cin? 
could you put some examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `std::cin`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line);) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ifstream` to open your file and `getline` function to read it line by line. You don't need to use `<` to pass param to your program. The param can be get in the argv array of your main function

Comment: That's a good option, but I'm forced in the exercise to use the program like that. I NEED to use the "<".